# How to Verify Email in Django using OTP and UserCreationForm

Tags: django, authentication, email-verification, totp, abstractuser

I am creating a Quiz App. In that I have a sign up page for user authentication which is using the default User Model and User CreationForm. I want to add a email verification in it by sending a otp on the email.

Please explain me how can I send otp on email using default user model and user creation form to verify the otp on the email.

My user app code is:

forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

```
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

views.py

import pyotp
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            otp=pyotp.totp('base32secret3232')
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account Created for {User.username}. You can Login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: For development purpose you can use [**`Django-doc EmailBackend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#email-backends) this [post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) explain how to send email.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer below article.

[https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-implement-otp-based-authentication-on-django-rest-framework-185ae8032f07#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Find%20that%20phone,the%20authenticity%20of%20the%20user](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-implement-otp-based-authentication-on-django-rest-framework-185ae8032f07#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Find%20that%20phone,the%20authenticity%20of%20the%20user).